# use copy command to copy TextBlock.Text in DataGrid RowDetails using MVVM-Light

Tags: mvvm, datagrid, mvvm-light

I am fairly new to WPF and I am trying to re-write a WPF control using MVVM-Light.  It is turning out to be more of an effort than I would have thought.  Here is some background:

This is a winforms application that has an ElementHost that contains the WPF control.  I originally wrote the WPF portion all wrong, but it does work.  The WPF control has a WPF Toolkit DataGrid that has several databound columns as well as a row details area with databound items.  All items are display only and bound to TextBlock objects.  In the current iteration, right clicking on any of the TextBlock elements in a record shows a context menu that allows the text of the TextBlock be copied to the clip board.

This was done by hooking the PreviewMouseDown button, looking at e.OriginalSource, walking the visual tree until we find the TextBlock and caching it.

When the copy command is requested, 'can copy' checks to see if there is a TextBlock 'copy object' and extracts the value by using the Text property.  Not elegant, but it does work.  This was all done in code behind of the wpf control.

I am trying to duplicate this behavior (right click and copy a TextBlock text value) in a MVVM manner.  It would be cool if it worked with ctl-c, but that's not necassary.  The context menu is suffucient.

I have been banging my head against this for a couple of days, so it's time to see if anyone can help.  Here is what I have tried so far.

1. Tried using an extension, but wasn't sure at all how to make this work.  I did read a lot on extensions and everything seemed to imply this was one method that should work.  I just couldn't wrap my head around it.
2. Tried attaching a behavior that hooks the ApplicationCommands.Copy to the VM.  This works, and I make it to my 'can copy' and 'executed' methods in the VM, but I don't have enough information to find the TextBlock that was clicked so I can get the text from it.
3. Started to go down the same path by using EventToCommand on the mouse click and grabbing the text via a converter so that it can be cached in the VM.  The handlers in 2 could then act on the 'copy value' if it exists.  This seems like it might get me close, but still feels a bit like a hack.

Without any input, I will likely chose option 3 as it does keep code down to only 2 places, in a converter and the VM and the method currently works.  It does seem there should be an easier way of doing this.

I am at the point that I felt it was worth seeing what ideas others might have to offer.

thanks in advance for any input,

Adding screen shot and code as requested:

Essentially I need to copy whatever text is contained in the displayed text box.  Notice that the columns are bound to the members, but the details relies on the .ToString() method.  Any text displayed needs to be able to be copied as what you see.

turns out i am too new to post an image.  The GUI is very simple so i hope code only is sufficient.

here is the code used to build that GUI:

```
<Window x:Class="DemoCopy.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:dg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DemoCopy"
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main}"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <dg:DataGrid Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding NamesList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <dg:DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Copy" Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </dg:DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <dg:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="1" Background="White" Padding="10">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </dg:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
            <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding First}" Width="*">
                <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>First Name</dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding First}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding Middle}" Width="50">
                <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>Middle Name</dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Middle}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding Last}" Width="*">
                <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>Last Name</dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Last}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
    </dg:DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

```
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private IList<Model.Name> namesList;
    public IList<Model.Name> NamesList
    {
        get { return namesList; }
        set
        {
            if (namesList == value)
                return;
            namesList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("NamesList");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        if (IsInDesignMode)
        {
            NamesList = new List<Model.Name>();
            NamesList.Add(new Model.Name()
            {
                First = "John",
                Middle = "M",
                Last = "Doe"
            });
            NamesList.Add(new Model.Name()
            {
                First = "Jane",
                Middle = "P",
                Last = "Doe"
            });
        }
        else
        {
            NamesList = new List<Model.Name>();
            NamesList.Add(new Model.Name()
            {
                First = "John",
                Middle = "M",
                Last = "Doe"
            });
            NamesList.Add(new Model.Name()
            {
                First = "Jane",
                Middle = "P",
                Last = "Doe"
            }); 
        }
    }
}

public class Name
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Middle { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", First, Middle, Last);
    }
}
```

scot.

Comment: Could you please attach a screenshot and add the source code to have better understanding of the problem?